# How to keep track of selected Item in a list being represented by tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

If I select a row, and rotate the device, I have a completely different layout for orientations.
I would like to keep track of last selected item which I can re-do after rotation in the new layout.

So, should I ideally store the selected indexPath, selected row number or the selected model object being represented in each cell from the dataSource  ?

I tried storing the selected cell, but it it creates problem when reused.

Comment: Save the selected IndexPath. You can keep track of them in a stack if you want to keep track of multiple cells, and push and pop as you need.

Comment: So you're saying `[UITableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` is different after the device rotates?

Comment: @trojanfoe: The selection looks different in landscape and portrait.
I want to re-do it.

Comment: But is the returned IndexPath different?

Comment: No it wont be. but I will be unselecting the cell before as rotation happens.
and re-select it.

at that time indexPathForSelectedRow wont help.
I am reloading the tableView after rotation.

This time , cell's UI, selection state UI everything is totally different for which is decided in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

at that time I would like to know If the cell was selected.
So I have to maintain it separately in an instance.

So as a good practice, shall I store the model of the selected cell or the index, or the indexPath just in case sections arrive.

Comment: Sounds like you need to store the *attributes of the selected cell* (enough to find it after rotation) before rotation, deselect, reload, etc. and then re-select.  If you have Model objects within the cells, then this becomes much easier.  "M, V, C, easy as 1, 2, 3".  Sing it.

Comment: So, basically apart from the information the model is displaying.
I should be storing information about the selection state of the model in the model itself rather than making it as a property of the Cell.
each time I update the cell with a model, automatically it should take the UI.

Got it.

Comment: BTW saw ur profile. ur 'skills' array pointer is that of NSMutableArray but @[] literal syntax will give you immutableArray.

just add a call to mutableCopy! otherwise u wont be able to add more skills :P :P
Otherwise .. nice style!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use same data for new layout, saving the selected indexPath would be enough I think so. But if you use data differently, means it can be at different index (if you do some process after rotation), then you need to save that as well.

**EDIT**

Before creating new layout for new orientation, find selected indexpath of selected cell and save it. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, check if it is present at that indexPath and make its state as selected. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize a `NSMutableArray *selectedItems`. (alloc-init in `viewDidLoad`)

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, check

```
if ([selectedItems indexOfObject:indexPath] == NSNotFound)  // if not available
{
     [selectedItems addObject: indextPath]
}

// if you are having deselect option as well then you can have else statement as well
else 
{
     [selectedItems removeObject: indexPath];
}
```

So now in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` while cell initialization,

first draw a normal cell with all properties and at the end check:

```
if ([selectedItems indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound)  // if current indexpath is selected
{
     // then display your selected cell [checkbox or different bg color as per your requirements]
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: ![selectedItems indexOfObject:indexPath] will be true if the index is 0 as well.
use NSNotFound instead. that is what is returned when object is not found.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I was just trying to give a logic to fulfill your requirement. And yes you are right, please check my updated answer.

Comment: look at the comments by  trojanfoe under the question. I think that is a better approach.

We are already maintaining a dataSource of models. Doesnt make sense to have another array of indexPaths.

Model should have all the info.